# Whatever happened to Uso's dad?

Tags: mobile-suit-gundam, mobile-suit-victory-gundam

In *[Mobile Suit Victory Gundam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Suit_Victory_Gundam)*, Uso Ewin's father, Hangelg, is present in the final battle of the series on the bridge of the Earth Federation's flagship, the Jeanne D'Arc. Late into the battle, the commander of the Jeanne D'Arc glances over at the seat where Hangelg was sitting and notes that it is empty. At first, I thought this implied that Uso's father hoofed it to avoid getting killed, but when the Jeanne D'Arc rams into the Zanscare fleet and explodes, there is a flash of both the commander and Hangelg's faces on the screen. Uso never mentions his father for the rest of the series, and seems unaware if anything happened to him.

My question is: is there any concrete evidence on what happened to Hangelg? Did he flee the scene, or did he simply just leave the bridge and was somewhere else on board the Jeanne D'Arc when it sunk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Is] there any concrete evidence on what happened to Hangelg?

Apparently not. According to [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/MobileSuitVictoryGundam):

> Hangelg disappears during the final battle, apparently having evacuated the doomed Jeanne D'Arc, and is never seen or mentioned after that. Uso sees a vision of his father as the Reinforce explodes, implying that he was on the ship, but that doesn’t explain where Hangelg was during its final run.

So we simply don't know.